# Can't login as ThingsBoard System admin on demo.thingsboard.io

Tags: thingsboard

I can't log in as ThingsBoard System admin on demo.thingsboard.io.

I thought that the solution would be here:

https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/demo-account/

Here it says that I should use the sysadmin@thingsboard.org user with password sysadmin. But that seems to be invalid. Perhaps this only works if I download a version of the ThingsBoard web to run on my local machine?

Comment: Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 0):

Well it worked if I downloaded ThingsBoard to run on my local machine, so I guess the problem is solved.